# Why won't my 'really simple' scrapy CrawlSpider connect to any pages?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have addressed the documentation. But must have overlooked something elemental. It is just a spider that starts at http://quotes.toscrape.com/, then uses only one rule and parsing function that logs the link. But it won't crawl any pages, not even the 'start_urls'.

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class Crawl_All(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Crawl_All'
    strat_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='Parse_for_new_url', follow=True),
            ]

    def Parse_for_new_url(self, response):
        self.logger.log('got a new url:', response.url)
```

here is the output:

```
2020-02-27 13:58:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: Auto_Contest)
2020-02-27 13:58:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) - [GCC 7.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Linux-5.3.0-40-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid
2020-02-27 13:58:55 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'Auto_Contest', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Auto_Contest.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Auto_Contest.spiders']}
2020-02-27 13:58:55 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 928bba99b8a0c238
2020-02-27 13:58:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-02-27 13:58:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-02-27 13:58:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-02-27 13:58:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-02-27 13:58:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-02-27 13:58:56 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-02-27 13:58:56 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-02-27 13:58:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-02-27 13:58:56 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 27, 12, 58, 56, 114277),
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'memusage/max': 54910976,
 'memusage/startup': 54910976,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 27, 12, 58, 56, 104321)}
2020-02-27 13:58:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

**EDIT:** Solved, seems like it was due to just a simple typo `strat_urls` should have been `start_urls`

Comment: BTW: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes and `lower_case_namese` for functions/methods/variables. See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You has simple typo in `strat_urls` which should be `start_urls`

---

You have to also use in `log()` two values:

- information what type of message you send (ie. warning, debug, etc),
- single string - so you have to concatenate `'got a new url:' + response.url`

You can also use predefined functions and then you don't need first argument but still you have to use single string

```
self.logger.warning('got a new url:' + response.url)
```

---

My code which can be run without creating project

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class Crawl_All(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Crawl_All'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='Parse_for_new_url', follow=True),]

    def Parse_for_new_url(self, response):
        #print(response.url)
        self.logger.warning('got a new url:' + response.url)

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(Crawl_All)
c.start()
```

Comment: Many thanks, seems like it was just a typo... Will look into the logging also.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because you are not using the `parse()` class method with your spider, which may be required. I suggest trying to make your spider fit the form below and then run crawl on it. If you need to do more specific scraping from there you can chain other parsing scripts, but I think you need to have your own defined `parse()` first and work from there.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'testspider'
start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

def parse(self, response):
    print(response.url)
```

Comment: I will try it out, but the scrapy documentation explicitly warns against using the parse function for a CrawlSpider class, since it is used internally to implement its logic. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules EDIT: it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: You're right, that should only be done for a Spider subclass. I've just noticed, where do you actually use any of the URL's within start_urls ? You define it, but you never actually use the urls within the list to generate a request.

Comment: also from the documentation: " start_urls: A list of URLs where the spider will begin to crawl from, when no particular URLs are specified. So, the first pages downloaded will be those listed here. The subsequent Request will be generated successively from data contained in the start URLs." i.e. it automatically triggers a request() to the urls listed, i also understand it so that the rules are then applied to all requested urls. but i am not sure. it just seems like so from the tutorials i did.

Comment: You've misspelled  `start_urls` as `strat_urls` so this could probably be why it's not picking up on them if it does look for that particular namespace.